# What is an idiomatic way of looping with a match when I only care about one variant and not even the value in the variant?

Tags: loops, rust, pattern-matching

```
loop {
    match stream.write(&buffer) {
        Ok(_) => break,
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

Is there a way to write it on a more readable/idiomatic way? I don't  need to do anything inside the `match`, I don't need any actions after the `Ok` or after the `Err`, because the buffer is updated as a reference whenever it returns `Ok`.

Something like:

```
while match some_fn() != Ok() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general case is covered by [ForceBru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64451558/155423), but since you have a `Result` and don't care about the value inside `Ok`, you can use [`Result::is_ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.is_ok) (or [`Result::is_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.is_err)):

```
while stream.write(&buffer).is_err() {}
```

As pointed out by [rodrigo in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64451464/what-is-an-idiomatic-way-of-looping-with-a-match-when-i-only-care-about-one-vari#comment113967823_64451546):

> Worth noting that Rust 1.42 adds the `matches!` macro, so you can write `while matches!(stream.write(&buffer), Ok(_)) {}`, useful for other enums that lack the `is_*` functions.

Comment: Ended going with `while !stream.write(& buffer).is_ok() {};`. Short and concise way.

Comment: @TheSylex `while stream.write(&buffer).is_err() {}`

Comment: @prog-fh nothing subtle here. I just tried (and failed) to collapse OPs exact logic down. Normal code doesn't look like this (looping forever when an error occurs? Sounds like a bad time) so my brain didn't reduce it correctly.

Comment: Let's be explicit: about no normal code just loops until it stops failing on IO operation.

Comment: Worth noting that Rust 1.42 adds the `matches!` macro, so you can write `while matches!(stream.write(&buffer), Ok(_)) {}`, useful for other enums that lacks the `is_*` functions.

Comment: @DenysSéguret it does happen from time to time e.g. you've got an unreliable remote (USB device?) which takes ages to properly come online. Although you'd usually sleep a bit instead of keep hammering away continuously there are situations where it doesn't matter and starting to send earlier is more valuable.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`while let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/flow_control/while_let.html):

```
fn some_fn(x: u32) -> Option<u32> {
    if x > 30 {
        Some(x)
    } else {
        None
    }
} 

fn main() {
    let mut x = 0;
    while let None = some_fn(x) {
        x += 1;
    }
    
    dbg!(x);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b6200bbece8801126766429370383451)

Same with the `Result` type: check if `some_fn` returned `Err`.

Comment: Although this is useful for more advanced cases, the answer of Shepmaster is what I was looking for, thank you anyway!